# JqGrid depend on number of returned records

Tags: jqgrid

In server side I implemented a cloud system

so when JQGrid send a request to server with `rownumber` 10 there my be more records

for example in beck-end there may be 3 server,

server 1: returned 10 records

2: returned 10 records

3: returned 7 records.

So all records are 27 but JqGrid just show 10 of them in one page
and by next page it send another request to server.

"a good JQGrid ! must know there are 3 page in 2 paging request don't send to server by third paging new Request will send to server to fetch next 10 records"

I have a JQGrid configed like this:

```
  $("#ExamGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '../Handlers/Study/StudySearch.ashx',
            editurl: '../Handlers/Study/StudySearch.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            beforeRequest: function () { 
            },
            postData: { 
            },
            //autowidth: true,  // set 'true' here
            //shrinkToFit: true,
            height: 'auto',
            autoencode: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            forceFit: false,
            colModel: $.evalJSON(colModel), 
            loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
            },
            onPaging: function () { 
            },
            resizeStop: function () {
                SaveColumns();
            },
            onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
                //   studyInstanceUID = rowid; 
            },
            multiselect: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            page: parameters.PageIndex,
            gridview: true,
            sortname: 'Study Date',
            prmNames: { nd: null },
            hidegrid: false,
            sortable: false,
            jsonReader: { cell: "", search: "isSearch" },
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            caption: 'Exam List',
            //viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', false],
            gridComplete: function () {
            });
```

In server side :

```
 IExamServiceJoinable examClient;
        if (Global.IsCloudConfigured)
            examClient = new DispatcherClient("dispatcherEndPoint", Token, Global.Cluster);
        else
            examClient = new ExamClient("examEndPoint");
        TotalPatient = examClient.GetNumberOfStudies(criteria); //study.Count(authorityWhereClause, criteria, sm ?? new SearchMatching());
        Start = ((pageIndex * numberOfRows) - numberOfRows);
        TotalPage = TotalPatient / numberOfRows;
        List<Study_C> studies = examClient.FindStudies(Start, numberOfRows, col.FromText(sortColumnName), sort.FromText(sortOrder), criteria);
```

In normal case when I fetch record from one server everything works like a charm but suppose `Global.IsCloudConfigured` is true so there may several servers and more DB to that service fetch records from them, in this case `studies` is more than requested `numberOfRows`.

now with above scenario how can I config JQGrid to load all of them in one page or any better way would be appreciated? 
How can I make a smart JQGrid to know that?

thanks in advance.

**Update:**
There is a very un-efficient way to add remains records to one page in `loadComplete` it works when returned records are low.

```
 if (data.IsCloudConfigured == true) {;
                    for (var i = 0; i <= data.rows.length - 1; i++) {
                        var rowData = $("#ExamGrid").jqGrid('getRowData', data.rows[i].StudyUID);
                        if (rowData.StudyUID === undefined) {
                            $("#ExamGrid").addRowData(data.rows[i].StudyUID, data.rows[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I correctly understand your problem. In the case the server (anyone from the servers on the cloud) need just return **all records** (27 rows of data) at once. You need just use `loadonce: true` option to inform jqGrid to fill local `data` based on the data returned from the server. It will allows to use local paging, sorting and filtering/searching.

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which I develop, then I would recommend you to use `forceClientSorting: true` option in combination with `loadonce: true`. It allows to sort and filter *locally* the data returned from the server before displaying there in the grid.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply,`loadonce` is not my solution, When the system is `CloudConfiged` this happened. in normal case I am returning 10 records in paging, I can't load all records in one request there are millions records.

Comment: @Aria: If you have the grid with millions records then the example with 27 have no relation to your problem. One choose the way depend on some numbers. If I need to visit my friend who lives 300 m from me then I walk, if hes home is 5 km from me then I use the car and if he is 5000 km from me then I choose the plane. You should more exactly formulate what you need to implement. You should modify the text of your question with more exact information. Do you need do use different URLs depend on the page number? Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid?

Comment: Sorry,  but I still not understand your problem. You write about `Global.IsCloudConfigured`, but it's not any common setting. If you use cloud then it could mean just the provide of the server. It gives no specific information about load balancing, distributed database and so on. If you have multiple servers with mirror of the same dataset then loading from any server should be OK because `page` and `rows` identify the requested page. What problem you have? You still use 27 as the total number of rows which need be loaded, which is another problem as loading of million rows.

Comment: @Aria: Moreover you still don't answer which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid. You used two tags: "jqgrid-asp.net" and "free-jqgrid" which means **different products**. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info).

Comment: @Aria: You wrote about requested "numberOfRows", but jqGrid request contains the page number and the page size only. The server should return the total number of rows. The value can be different in different responses from the server. I see no problem in general.

Comment: `numberOfRows` is `rows` , I tried to say what I want, you know when `Global.IsCloudConfigured` is true the returned records may more than requested `rows` which set to 10 by this JQGrid just show 10 of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120529/discussion-between-aria-and-oleg).

Comment: @Aria: It would be wrong response. The server have to return the requested number of `rows` (10) or less (in case of the last page of data). The server should returns **the current total number or pages**. If it was requested the page number 50055 of the size 10 and it's not the last page of data then `total` part of the server response will be the value larger as 50055. If the `total` part of the server response if larger as requested page then the "Next Page" button of the pager will be enabled.

Comment: Yes as you said Server should return requested number of `rows` but in this scenario each server may return requested number of `rows` so the passed records to client may be larger than .

Comment: @Aria: Sorry, but you use `url: '../Handlers/Study/StudySearch.ashx'`  it mean one specific server. Isn't so. In any way I can't follow you. You have implemented some code in some specific environment. **What problem you has? What is working not like you expect?** You started chat too. I posted some information in the chat too.

Comment: @Aria: You should understand that I have my main job which I have to do. I break it for a half of hour after receiving your email to help you, but I don't see any essential progress. It would be better if you formulate your problem more clear to save my time. I have to make some thing till the end for my customer. Sorry, but the discussion takes too many time...

Comment: I think I have to remove this question, I don't know why it is unclear.

Comment: @Aria: What problem you has? What is working not like you expect?